# Splicing and looping through specific indices of array in Swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Assume I have an array of UInt8

`let myArray: [UInt8] = [0xD0, 0xA4, 0xA3, 0xE0, 0xD1]`

1. How do I loop through indices 2 through 4? I know the various `for` loops exist but is there one that allows me to iterate through specific indices?
2. How do I create another array that contains only indices 0, 1 and 2?

Thank you in advance

Comment: In Swift 3 consider to use `Data` which is `UInt8`-based but much more versatile.

Comment: @vadian - hmm - i actually am using Data also but how do I extract specific indices etc from Data object? I actually have a `Data` object and then had to convert it to `myArray` for stuff like looping, splicing etc

Comment: @ChicagoSky Exactly the same way. `myData[2...4]` works.

Comment: @matt - so if I have a stream of 25 bytes in an NSData object - how would I do this? Are you suggesting that I can manipulate an NSData object similar to an array? That would be wow!

Comment: I'm not suggesting it. I'm _saying_ it. :) But not NSData. Data. That is the _point_ of Data. It is a Swift-native value-type facade in front of NSData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I loop through indices 2 through 4?

Like this:

```
let myArray: [UInt8] = [0xD0, 0xA4, 0xA3, 0xE0, 0xD1]

for i in myArray[2...4] {
    print(i)
}
```

> How do I create another array that contains only indices 0, 1 and 2?

Similar:

```
let myArray: [UInt8] = [0xD0, 0xA4, 0xA3, 0xE0, 0xD1]
let myOtherArray = myArray[0...2]
```

...but watch out: `myOtherArray` is now a *slice*, not an actual array. You can coerce to an Array if you need to.

**EDIT** Turns out you actually have a Data object. The notation remains the same:

```
for i in myData[2...4] { // myData is a Data
    print(i)
}
let myData2 = myData[0...2]
```

That is exactly *why* Apple provided the Data type (as opposed to Foundation's NSData), so that you *can* use array notation on it.

Comment: My online book would have helped you here: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_array_subscripting

Comment: Added same answer for a Data object.